# Mysql order by field subquery and variable not works

Tags: mysql

I have this query.

```
@var = "5,3,2,4,1,11";

SET @var := (select faq_order from config);


SELECT faq_id, faq_q,faq_a
FROM faqs
ORDER BY FIELD(faq_id, @var);
```

and i want to sort by this variable but not works

if i write this, it is works and orders data correctly.

```
SELECT faq_id, faq_q,faq_a
FROM faqs
ORDER BY FIELD(faq_id,5,3,2,4,1,11)
```

subquery also not works.

Comment: `FIELD(faq_id, @var)` becomes `FIELD(faq_id, '5,3,2,4,1,11')`, not `FIELD(faq_id,5,3,2,4,1,11)`

Comment: how fix it?.......

Comment: You should use prepared statement for this

Comment: Try This `SET @var := (select group_concat(faq_order) from config);`

Comment: prepared statement and group_concat not works. prepared statement from php also pases argument as string.